# Не работает ngrok сайт на смартфоне

Tags: websocket, веб-сайт

Запустил ngrok, чтобы протестировать сайт на смартфоне, но он (сайт) не отправляет запросы (я использую сокеты) на сервер, но на компьютере все замечательно работает. также в терминале ngrok есть запись (возможно, поможет):

> GET /Geocipher.html/ws 101 Switching Protocols

что мне нужно сделать, чтобы это исправить?